ts-node imports .js modules over .ts modules of the same name
Say I have an esm sayhi.ts module:
const sayhi = () => 'hi in typescript';
export default sayhi;

And then I have the same module but it's a commonjs sayhi.js file:
const sayhi = () => 'hi in javascript';
module.exports = sayhi;

And then I'm using ts-node to run index.ts:
import sayhi from "./sayhi";
console.log(sayhi()); // returns 'hi in javascript'

It seems to always return the sayhi.js module not sayhi.ts. How do I get ts-node or ts-node-dev to prioritize importing .ts files before .js files, mostly just for dev purposes. Also this is my tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}


You want the preferTsExts option. https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/options#prefertsexts
